# How to do unrar operation in SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, unrar

I am trying to unrar the dataset for my object detection model, but I couldn't unrar the compressed file in AWS's SageMaker.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz', 'rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz')
!tar -xvzf rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz
%cd rar
!make
!sudo make install
%cd ..
!unrar x {your_rar_file}.rar
```

Don't forget to check the current rarlinux version.